# Require one field, if another doesn't exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, https

To post a message to MongoDB i need to send a schema with a required `text` field. But even `media` field exists (as optional) - you can send request without `text` field. How should I do it? Here is a code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var Message = new Schema({
   text: {type: String, required: true},
   media: {type: Object, required: false}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this using function validation as mentioned [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var Message = new Schema({
   text: {
    type: String,
    required: function() {
      return !this.media;
    }
   },
   media: {
    type: Object, 
    required: function() {
      return !this.text;
    }
})
```